# How do I load zipfile on Kaggle?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, kaggle

I'm having data files inside .zip folder which I'd like to load but I can't do the most basic syntax for the command as shown on the picture below:

[image]

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please dont put screen shots of code, if you have code then put it in the body the post

Comment: are you sure you've put the correct path to a zip file?

Comment: @politicalscientist Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by default the top level zip file in a Kaggle dataset is unzipped. You should be able to treat it as a directory.

Comment: Nope, it is not.

Comment: @StanislavJirak it looks like there's a space in your file path which might be causing some problems. Did you copy it from the file viewer/use tab complete to get it?